# Problem with closing login form after user is authenticated ,using VB

Tags: vb.net, forms, authentication

I have a very generic login form created that allows a user to access a application. My problem is getting the log in form to close after the application form is loaded. I have described the specifics in the comments of the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Class frmUserLogin
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Private pass As String
Private username As String
Private attempt As Integer = 0
Private Admin As String
Private Password As String

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    username = "Admin"
    pass = "Password"

    If (txtUsername.Text = username) And (txtPassword.Text = pass) Then
        MsgBox("That is correct")
        frmApplicationWindow.Show()

        'I am trying to close the login form after the user is able to load the frmapplicationwindow

        'frmUserLogin.close() , when I use this it says I can use it because it is referring to the same instance of itself
        'me.close , when I use this it closes both the user login form and the application form

    Else
        MsgBox("wrong username or pass, try again")
        attempt += 1
    End If

    If attempt = 3 Then
        MsgBox("You have reached the allowed number of login attempts")
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Me.Hide in place of Me.Close.